# Angular: ng2 smart table use rendercomponent for displaying custom actions

Tags: angular, angular5, ng2-smart-table

Can we display custom actions with a component? Like we do with the columns?

**I want to show the activate button when the user is blocked and the blocked button when the user is activated.**

```
    actions: {
    position: 'right',
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    delete: false,
    custom: [
        {
            name: 'activate',
            title: 'Activate',
            type: 'custom',
            renderComponent: UsersActionsActivateRenderComponent,
        },
        {
            name: 'block',
            title: `Block`,
            type: 'custom',
            renderComponent: UsersActionsBlockRenderComponent,
        },
    ]
},
```

I am trying to use a component for rendering the custom action so that i can apply some conditions on the actions. But it is just displaying the title attribute only.

Comment: did You find the solution?